# can't find file in shell

Tags: xml, cygwin, ksh

I need to read line by line a XML file by korn unix shell (.ksh).

i'm working on window 10 with cygwin.
shell file and xml file are in the same directory (/bin).

this is my code:

prova.ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo start
while read line; do    
   echo $line    
done < ./File1.xml
```

File1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RichiestaInserimento>
     <Iniziativa>1</Iniziativa>
     <Valutazione>1</Valutazione>
     <Motivazione>1</Motivazione>
</RichiestaInserimento>
```

when i try to run .ksh print `start` but i have this error:

```
/usr/bin/prova.ksh: riga 5: File1.xml: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please check if file is present on your path where you are running the script, if not then please add absolute path of that xml file in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if file is present on your path where you are running the script, if not then please add absolute path of that xml file in your code.

```
cat prova.ksh
#!/bin/ksh
echo start
while read line; do    
   echo $line    
done < "/your/complete/path/File1.xml"
```

Comment: Thank you so much !